Bumps on Benchy Cabin At One Spot


I have some strange bumps on the cabin on pretty much all of my benchies, and it seems to line up with the steering wheel. I tried many retraction settings, have e steps calibrated, have my linear advance calibrated and have decent acceleration/jerk settings. I'm not sure what else there is to try.
Printer: Ultimaker 2 Go (1.75 mm w/ klipper, e3d v6, cht high flow nozzle)
Slicer: Prusaslicer
Extruder type: Semi-bowden (see image above)
Layer Height: 0.2
Temp: 215 C / 50 C
Material: PLA
Small/external perimeters: 45 mm/s
Perimeters: 70 mm/s
Infill: 180 mm/s
Travel: 270 mm/s
Retraction Length: 2 mm
Retraction Speed: 50 mm/s
No Z-hop, no wipe while retracting
Square Corner Velocity: 7 mm/s
Acceleration: 3500 mm/s^2
Pressure Advance: 0.315s
Smooth Time: 0.04s

